# Using vectors in r

Tags: r, vector

The code below gives this error: Error: object 'z' not found

I'm new to r; can someone point out how I should do this?  I can't create a vector by assigning values to it?  Do I need to declare it somehow?

```
set.seed(1)
# simulate throwing 100 dice 10000 times
n <- 100
x <- replicate(10000,sample(1:6, n, replace=TRUE))
# calculate the scaled probability of throwing a 6
p <- 1/6
for (i in 1:ncol(x)) {
    z[i] = (mean(x[,c(i)]==6)  - p) / sqrt(p*(1-p)/n)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize z with `z <- c()` before `for` loop.

Comment: Or even better `z <- numeric(ncol(x))`. That way the vector won't be resized unnecessarily.